# How can I get cluster number correspond to data using k-means clustering techniques in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I clustered data by k-means clustering method,  how can i get cluster number correspond to data using k-means clustering techniques in R? In order to get each record belongs to which cluster.

example
`12  32  13   =>  1. 12,13   2. 32`

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you are trying to access the cluster vector that is returned by `kmeans()`. From the help page for cluster:

```
A vector of integers (from 1:k) indicating the cluster to which each 
point is allocated.
```

Using the example on the help page:

```
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
(cl <- kmeans(x, 2))

#Access the cluster vector
cl$cluster

> cl$cluster
  [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [45] 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [89] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

**To address the question in the comments**

You can "map" the cluster number to the original data by doing something like this:

```
out <- cbind(x, clusterNum = cl$cluster)
head(out)

               x          y clusterNum
[1,] -0.42480483 -0.2168085          2
[2,] -0.06272004  0.3641157          2
[3,]  0.08207316  0.2215622          2
[4,] -0.19539844  0.1306106          2
[5,] -0.26429056 -0.3249288          2
[6,]  0.09096253 -0.2158603          2
```

`cbind` is the function for column bind, there is also an `rbind` function for rows. See their help pages for more details `?cbind` and `?rbind` respectively.

Comment: how can i match this vector to my table, i would like to know cluster number which correspondent to each row of table. (extra column which is cluster number after k-means clustering)

Comment: cl$cluster is the vector of length 100 which in this example is the corresponding cluster number for the 100 rows in the input matrix. So the first row is cluster 2, the second row is cluster 2, etc etc until you get to row 27 which is cluster 1, then its all 2 again up to 51 and then 51 to 100 is in cluster 1. What part of that do you not understand?

Comment: thank you Spacedman,could you tell me, how i can map this vector with data table? is there function?

Comment: @Java - see my updated answer. Also, a lot of this data transformation type information is covered in the R Intro manual, which can be accessed here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html. Folks here are generally quite happy to help with questions basic and complex, but actively engaging the existing R resources is also encouraged. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Chase very useful, sorry i am very new on R

Answer (score 7):

@ Java questioner

You can access the cluster data as followed:

```
> data_clustered <- kmeans(data)
> data_clustered$cluster
```

`data_clustered$cluster` is a vector with the length of the original number of records in data. Each entry is for the that row.

To get all the records belonging to cluster 1:

```
> data$cluster <- data_clustered$cluster 
> data_clus_1 <- data[data$cluster == 1,]
```

Number of clusters:

```
> max(data$cluster)
```

Good luck with your clustering

Comment: how can i match this vector to my table, i would like to know cluster number which correspondent to each row of table. (extra column which is cluster number after k-means clustering)

Comment: Assuming that your data is stored in the matrix (not table!), 'x', a quick way is: clust_results <- cbind.data.frame(cluster = kmeans(x, centers = 4)$cluster, x)

Comment: Your table is in this example the data. This has a number of column and rows. Your samples are in the rows and observations in the columns. If you assign the extra column cluster to your table as described in the post, then you'll find on a per row basis the cluster number for that row in the column cluster.

Comment: Thanks Mischa, i understood now. it is done !

Answer (score 0):

We like reproducible examples here on Stack Overflow. Otherwise we're just guessing.

I'll guess that you are using kmeans in the stats package.

I'll further guess you haven't read the documentation help(kmeans) which says:

```
Value:

  an object of class 'kmeans' which is a list with components:

   cluster: A vector of integers indicating the cluster to which each point is allocated.
```

There's an example in the help that shows you exactly how that works.

Comment: how can i match this vector to my table, i would like to know cluster number which correspondent to each row of table. (extra column which is cluster number after k-means clustering)