# How to retrieve the original data points that belong to every cluster from dbscan algorithm using R

Tags: r

I am using `library("dbscan")` to cluster geographical data with latitude and longitude. I would like to know which coordinates [latitude, longitude] are belonging to which cluster in R. Is there any way to retrieve the original data points under each cluster?
Example:

> latitude = c(60.95886,63.04287,60.79435,61.79435, 64.79435, 61.95886,65.04287,66.79435,63.79435, 65.79435,66.79435, 68.79435,69.79435 )
>
> longitude = c(27.79045,22.87444,24.51007, 23.49429, 23.49429, 28.79045,23.87444,26.51007, 25.49429, 26.49429,26.49429, 29.49429,30.49429)
>
> testData = data.frame(latitude,longitude)
>
> clust <- dbscan(testData, eps = 1.5, minPts = 3)
>
> clust

```
DBSCAN clustering for 13 objects.
Parameters: eps = 1.5, minPts = 3
The clustering contains 2 cluster(s) and 7 noise points.

0 1 2 
7 3 3
```

Here I want to know the data points from *testData* belonging to cluster 1 and 2

Comment: you mean you want to assign each data point to a cluster Id, or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want to know which data points are belonging to which cluster Id. I update my question with sample data.

Comment: and why does this output not answer your question?: `clust$cluster`

Comment: `clust$cluster` gives the cluster, but not the data points belonging to a given cluster. Thanks though.

Comment: `clus$cluster` is the vector of the cluster Ids and corresponds exactly to the order of the points of your data.frame. You just have to `cbind` it to your data.frame, or create a new column (this is really basic R coding)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get cluster number correspond to data using k-means clustering techniques in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278966/how-can-i-get-cluster-number-correspond-to-data-using-k-means-clustering-techniq)

Answer (score 1):

add the output of dbscan to your initial data.frame.

```
testData$cluster = clust$cluster
```